Understanding Loop Formation in a Plucked String
I have a question regarding the formation of loops when a string is plucked at different fractional lengths.
In a book I referenced, it is stated that plucking a string at 1/6 of its length produces 3 loops. However, based on other sources I've read, the understanding is different.
From what I've gathered:
Plucking a string at half its length ($L/2$) produces 1 loop.
Plucking at $L/4$ produces 2 loops.
Therefore, for 3 loops, it seems logical that the length should be L/8, following a general formula of $L/2^n$, where $n$ represents the number of loops.
For example:
To get 1 loop, $n=1$, so $L/2^1 = L/2$.
To get 2 loops, $n=2$, so $L/2^2 = L/4$.
To get 3 loops, $n=3$, so $L/2^3 = L/8$.
Can someone clarify if this reasoning is correct, or explain why a string plucked at 1/6 of its length would produce 3 loops?


One simple way to get some intuition is to think of it like this: After plucking, the string would like to relax into a sinusoidal wave which is zero at the edges and has a maximum amplitude (antinode) where it was plucked. In your case, the three loop wave has its antinodes at the points $x = L/6, L/2, 5L/6 $. This indeed is a sinusoidal wave with an antinode at the plucking spot.
Based on this, we would expect the following relation: A standing wave fits an integer number of nodes on the string, and these will be separated by $\lambda/2$ as in your illustration. To get $n$ loops you need to pluck an antinode of this wave. The first antinode will be at $x=\lambda/4$. For $n$ loops on a string of length $L$, the wavelength is given by $n \lambda/2 = L \Rightarrow \lambda = 2L/n$, and therefore the plucking point is at $x = L/(2n)$. Let us check this against the first three results:

$n=1, x = L/2$
$n=2, x = L/4$
$n=3, x = L/6$
Etc.

This is just the intuition, and not necessarily the full picture. Hopefully the book explains this in more technical detail, otherwise I would advise you to look around for deeper answers, see e.g. this answer.

The main thing is if we plucked it from L/6 how it gives us 3 loops or we can call it 3rd mode of vibration.

@EngrFahadSafi I have updated my answer with a more general expression. Let me know if anything is unclear.

@EngrFahadSafi Please upvote the answer and mark it correct if it helped you.
